# Effective development with AWS Lambda Layers using gradle for Java, for a Spring Boot App

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I'm wanting to speed up my Lambda development productivity. My desired end state is to split my development process up into 2 different builds:

- Lambda Layer Build - builds my Lambda Layer which contains all dependencies of my project
- Application Code - the actual application without all the dependencies

I'm happy to make use of `serverless framework` integration with Lambdas, but I'm still having problems figuring out how to get gradle of instead of building a FatJar, to have one folder/jar containing all dependencies, and one of only my application code.

I've tried this tutorial [here](https://medium.com/consulner/speedup-aws-lambda-deployments-with-layers-12f8f24c7d0) which does something like:

```java
task buildZip(type: Zip) {
    baseName = "aws-java-github-webhook-gitstats"
    from compileJava
    from processResources
//    into('lib') {
//        from configurations.runtime
//    }
}


task buildLayer(type: Copy) {
    into "$buildDir/layer/java/lib"
    from configurations.runtime
}
```

But I think the `spring-dependency` plugin is messing that approach up, (I am using `spring-boot`). Does anyone have a nice configuration setup to do this which I could leverage?